# Can split pandas dataframe based on row values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that effectively contains several different datasets. Between each dataset is a row full of NaN. Can I split the dataframe on the NaN row to make two dataframes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.isnull.any(axis=1).cumsum())`

Comment: @PaulH typo? `isnull()`. I think OP also meant `all` instead of `any`.

Comment: @Ehsan yeah `isnull()` from the OPs description it sounds like either might work, but `all` would be the safer bet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to split into many data frames based on all NaN rows:

```
#index of all NaN rows (+ beginning and end of df)
idx = [0] + df.index[df.isnull().all(1)].tolist() + [df.shape[0]]
#list of data frames split at all NaN indices
list_of_dfs = [df.iloc[idx[n]:idx[n+1]] for n in range(len(idx)-1)]
```

And if you want to exclude the NaN rows from split data frames:

```
idx = [-1] + df.index[df.isnull().all(1)].tolist() + [df.shape[0]]
list_of_dfs = [df.iloc[idx[n]+1:idx[n+1]] for n in range(len(idx)-1)]
```

Example:

df:

```
     0    1
0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  1.0
2  1.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
5  1.0  1.0
6  1.0  1.0
7  NaN  1.0
8  1.0  NaN
9  1.0  NaN
```

list_of_dfs:

```
[     0    1
0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  1.0
2  1.0  NaN, 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1]
Index: [],   

     0    1
5  1.0  1.0
6  1.0  1.0
7  NaN  1.0
8  1.0  NaN
9  1.0  NaN]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `df[df[COLUMN_NAME].isnull()].index.tolist()` to get a list of indices corresponding to the NaN rows. You can then split the dataframe into multiple dataframes by using the indices.

Answer (score 0):

My solution allows to split your DataFrame into **any** number of chunks,
on each row full of *NaN*s.

Assume that the input DataFrame contains:

```
       A    B     C
0   10.0  Abc  20.0
1   11.0  NaN  21.0
2   12.0  Ghi   NaN
3    NaN  NaN   NaN
4    NaN  Hkx  30.0
5   21.0  Jkl  32.0
6   22.0  Mno  33.0
7    NaN  NaN   NaN
8   30.0  Pqr  40.0
9    NaN  Stu   NaN
10  32.0  Vwx  44.0
```

so that "split points" are rows with indices *3* and *7*.

To do your task:

1. Generate the grouping criterion *Series*:

   ```
    grp = (df.isnull().sum(axis=1) == df.shape[1]).cumsum()
   ```
2. Drop rows full of *NaN* and group the result by the above criterion:

   ```
    gr = df.dropna(axis=0, thresh=1).groupby(grp)
   ```

   `thresh=1` means that for the current row it is enough to have *1*
   non-*NaN* value to be kept in the result.
3. Perform actual split, as a list comprehension:

   ```
    result = [ gr.get_group(key) for key in gr.groups ]
   ```

To print the result, you can run:

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(result):
    print(f'Chunk {i}:')
    print(chunk, end='\n\n')
```

getting:

```
Chunk 0:
      A    B     C
0  10.0  Abc  20.0
1  11.0  NaN  21.0
2  12.0  Ghi   NaN

Chunk 1:
      A    B     C
4   NaN  Hkx  30.0
5  21.0  Jkl  32.0
6  22.0  Mno  33.0

Chunk 2:
       A    B     C
8   30.0  Pqr  40.0
9    NaN  Stu   NaN
10  32.0  Vwx  44.0
```